# adding custom html in wordpress admin between filters and posts table

Tags: wordpress, filter, hook, admin

I am developing a plugin and using custom post types. I have done all of the work that I have to do but stuck with a point i.e. I want to display some custom html right between the filters and posts table. Please check the attached image for more details. Any help will be appreciated. thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to JQuery, I have added a new document ready function, added my html and then from page html see an id of the div where I want to add my html and then using .appen() I have added the html to the specified location.
It is not the good solution but I have searched for more than a week and got nothing so I have used this kind of illegal work :)